# Tomcat Request.getPort() stripping port number

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

**Problem:**

I am using Java HttpServeltResponse to call sendRedirect but on a particular deployment the URL port number is not included in the HTTP 302 response message.

**Details:**

I have an application, which uses spring security to authenticate and redirect on success.  The redirection URL provided by me is a relative path.

On redirection the spring framework calls sendRedirect on HttpServletResponse passing in the context path along with the relative URL.  For example:

HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect("/MyApp/index.html");

This all works fine when we deploy to tomcat instances on various platforms (Windows/Ubuntu etc).  However one of our clients is finding that in their deployment, the redirection port is stripped, for example, if the entry point is:

```
http://server:8082/MyApp/authenticate
```

The redirection they get is:
`http://server/MyApp/index.html`  - this page does not exist, as it is missing port 8082

Stepping through the code, I can see that the port is determined by asking the Java Request Object, which seems to be supplied by the Web Application Container (i.e Jetty/Tomcat?). In my dev environment it is org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.

So is this a tomcat configuration issue?  We could replicate the same behaviour using Apache2 ProxyPassReverse, but they assure me they are not running Apache2, and their connection is a direct connection to tomcat.

As I can not replicate this issue anywhere, I am really stuck for an answer.  Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I would double check your client's statements. For example dump of low-level network communication (`tcpdump` / `Wireshark`) might reveal some deployment inconsistency. Also ask for exact Tomcat version and check their issue tracker.